# Test an instrument's correlation with unobservable when it's redundant in structural equation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics, instrumental-variables, omitted-variable-bias

I'm working on Wooldridge's “Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data” and I don't fully get why this test would not work.

[image]

I'll share my work with screenshots so it's clearer hope that's okay.

I start with:

$$y_1=z_1\delta_1+\alpha_1y_2+z_2\lambda_1+\gamma q+a_1\qquad(1)$$

Because the exercise states that $z_2$ is redundant in the structural equation that means that the coefficient, if we were to introduce it unto the structural equation, should be $0,$ correct? So both equations are the same in that case.
Then I take the linear projection on the unobservable:

$$L(q\,|\,z_1,z_2,y_2)=z_1d_1+d_2y_2+z_2d_3$$

And I plug it in on error form (also, $z_1$ is uncorrelated with $q$ so that coefficient $= 0$) on (1):

$$y_1=z_1\delta_1+(\alpha_1+\gamma d_2)y_2+z_2(\lambda_1+\gamma d_3)+\gamma r+a_1$$

So this is the same regression as the one suggested for the test ($y_1$ regressed on $z_1, y_2$ and $z_2$).

$$\psi_1=\lambda_1+\gamma d_3$$

If the estimated $\psi_1$ is different than $0,$ wouldn't that mean that it's correlated with $q$ $(d_3$ different than $0)?$ Since $\lambda_1$ is by definition $0.$

Am I just not getting any of it?

Thanks in advance